# Mine Sweeper project

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python, and i have was given a 2d list that contains '-' and '#', where the hashtags are bombs, my output is meant to replace all the '-' with a count that shows all the bombs around the cell

So if someone could please walk me through how to do this step by step, it would really mean a lot, this is a campus project , and ive been stuck on it for quite some time now

My Code so far:

```
mines = [ ['-', '-', '-', '#', '#'],
         ['-', '#', '-', '-', '-'],
         ['-', '-', '#', '-', '-'],
         ['-', '#', '#', '-', '-'],
         ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ] ]

counter = 0

for row in range(len(mines)):
    for cols in range(len(mines)):
        
        if mines[row][cols] == '-':
            if mines[row - 1][cols - 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if mines[row - 1][cols] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if mines[row - 1][cols + 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if mines[row][cols - 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if mines [row][cols + 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if mines[row + 1][cols - 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if mines[row + 1][cols] == '#':
                counter += 1 
            if mines[row + 1][cols + 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            mines[row][cols] = str(counter)


            
print(mines)
```

I get an index error by the 3rd if statement, i assume its because im looking outside the grid, and cant seem to fix it, id like to use a function method as well if thats possible

Comment: You have to consider the boundaries, when you have index 0 or cols-1, you should skip the check for the left/right non-existing cell. Something like `if col - 1 < 0: continue` etc.

Comment: can i add it just like that to my code?

Comment: Actually no, you need to add the condition like `if row>0 and cols>0 and mines[row - 1][cols - 1] == '#'`: …`

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to dealing with this issue.

One is the "look-before-you-leap" approach, which in this case would mean making sure that you're trying to access the lists at valid indices - something along the lines of what @mozway suggested.

The second is "ask forgiveness, not permission" - wrap the part of the code which tries to access the potentially invalid indices in a `try/except` block, catch the relevant `IndexError` and deal with it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility, with all manual checks:

```
counts = [[' ' for _ in range(len(mines))] for _ in range(len(mines))]
for row in range(len(mines)):
    for cols in range(len(mines)):
        counter = 0
        if mines[row][cols] == '-':
            if row > 0:
                if cols > 0 and mines[row - 1][cols - 1] == '#':
                    counter += 1
                if mines[row - 1][cols] == '#':
                    counter += 1
                if cols < len(mines)-1 and mines[row - 1][cols + 1] == '#':
                    counter += 1
            if cols > 0 and mines[row][cols - 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if cols < len(mines)-1 and mines [row][cols + 1] == '#':
                counter += 1
            if row < len(mines)-1:
                if cols > 0 and mines[row + 1][cols - 1] == '#':
                    counter += 1
                if mines[row + 1][cols] == '#':
                    counter += 1 
                if cols < len(mines)-1 and mines[row + 1][cols + 1] == '#':
                    counter += 1
            counts[row][cols] = str(counter)
print(counts)
```

output:

```
[['1', '1', '2', ' ', ' '],
 ['1', ' ', '3', '3', '2'],
 ['2', '4', ' ', '2', '0'],
 ['1', ' ', ' ', '2', '0'],
 ['1', '2', '2', '1', '0']]
```

For a real project I would rather use appropriate tools, such as a matrix convolution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

grid = np.array(mines)

counts = convolve2d(grid=='#', np.ones((3,3)), mode='same')
```

output:

```
array([[1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 2., 3., 3., 2.],
       [2., 4., 4., 2., 0.],
       [1., 3., 3., 2., 0.],
       [1., 2., 2., 1., 0.]])
```

Or to mask the mines:

```
counts = np.where(grid=='-', convolve2d(grid=='#', np.ones((3,3)), mode='same'), -1)
```

output:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2., -1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1.,  3.,  3.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4., -1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 1., -1., -1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help, i really do appreciate. Can you please explain to me what the code for the counts variable is doing?

Comment: @VaashenDhanpat you cannot modify the grid while you iterate over it, else you will erase the previous mines. This is to create a separate grid for the counts

Comment: so is there a way to show the output where only the '-' change but the '#' are still in the grid?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible, you'd have to show the exact expected output for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version :

```py
def count_mines(minefield: List[List[str]], i: int, j: int) -> str:
    """Counts the number of mines around minefield[i][j]

    :param minefield: The minefield
    :type minefield: List[List[str]]
    :param i: row number
    :type i: int
    :param j: column number
    :type j: int
    :return: number of mines around minefield[i][j]
    :rtype: str
    """
    offsets: List[Tuple[int, int]] = [
        (0, 1),
        (1, 0),
        (1, 1),
        (0, -1),
        (-1, 0),
        (-1, -1),
        (-1, 1),
        (1, -1),
    ]  # pre-generate offsets
    count: int = sum(
        [
            minefield[i + offset[0]][j + offset[1]] == "#"
            for offset in offsets
            if (
                0 <= i + offset[0] < len(minefield)
                and 0 <= j + offset[1] < len(minefield)
            )  # make sure the offset is in range
        ]  # list of booleans
    )
    return str(count)


def annotate(minefield: List[List[str]]) -> List[List[str]]:
    """Return a new annotated minefield

    :param minefield: The minefield to be annotated
    :type minefield: List[List[str]]
    :return: the new annotated minefield
    :rtype: List[List[str]]
    """
    res: List[List[str]] = []  # init the new minefield
    for (i, row) in enumerate(
        minefield
    ):  # iterate over minefield rows ; enumerate returns the tuple (index, value)
        tmp_row: List[str] = []  # init the new row
        for (j, val) in enumerate(row):  # iterate over row values
            if val == "-":
                tmp_row.append(
                    count_mines(minefield, i, j)
                )  # call the count_mines function and append the result to the new row
            else:
                # we do not consider anything other than - and #
                tmp_row.append("#")  # mines do not need to be changed
        res.append(tmp_row)  # append the new row to the new minefield
    return res


annotated_mines: List[List[str]] = annotate(mines)
print(annotated_mines)
```

**Output: **

```
[['1', '1', '2', '#', '#'],
 ['1', '#', '3', '3', '2'],
 ['2', '4', '#', '2', '0'],
 ['1', '#', '#', '2', '0'],
 ['1', '2', '2', '1', '0']]
```

Comment: hi sorry im really confused to whats happening in your code, should minefield be by 2d list?

Comment: @VaashenDhanpat minefield represent your 2D list